# Issue with populating partial view with AngularJs and MVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to AngularJs. I am using a partial view for Create and Edit operation but facing some issue wile retrieving the data.

The data is being retrieved successfully from my MVC controller but is unable to populate the view.

Here is the JS I am using

```
 (function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('Sub_Ledger_Category_Create_app', [])
.controller('Sub_Ledger_Category_Create_ctrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

    $scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel = {};
    GetRequestType();

    function GetRequestType() {
        $http.get('/Common/Get_Action_Request')
        .success(function (result) {
            //debugger;
            // $scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel = data;

            if (result == "Create") {
                $("#txt_Master_Subledger_Category").html("<h3  class='box-title'> Create Sub Ledger Category </h3>");
                // $("#txt_Master_Accounting_Group_Group_id").val(0);

            }
            else {
                $("#txt_Master_Subledger_Category").html("<h3  class='box-title'> Edit Sub Ledger Category</h3>");
                //GetEditData();
                $scope.GetEditData();
            }
            $("#Master_Subledger_Category").val(result)

            NProgress.done();
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            NProgress.done();
            $("div.failure").text("Unable to retrieve Request Type");
            $("div.failure").fadeIn(300).delay(1500).fadeOut(400);
        });
    };

     $scope.GetEditData = function () {
        $http.get('/Master_Subledger_Category/GetEditData')
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            debugger;
             $scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel = data;

            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            NProgress.done();
             $("div.failure").text("Retrive Failure");
             $("div.failure").fadeIn(300).delay(1500).fadeOut(400);
        });
    };


    $scope.InsertSubledgerCategory = function () {
        NProgress.start();
        var Request_Type = $("#Master_Subledger_Category").val();

        var Url_Master_Subledger;
        if (Request_Type == "Create") {
            Url_Master_Subledger = "/Master_Subledger_Category/Create_Master_Subledger_Category_Ajax";
        }
        else {
            Url_Master_Subledger = "/Master_Subledger_Category/Test";
        }

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: Url_Master_Subledger,
            data: $scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data.success === true) {
                NProgress.done();
                $("div.success").text("Successfully Created");
                $("div.success").fadeIn(300).delay(1500).fadeOut(800);
                $scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel = {};
                console.log(data);
            }
            else {
                NProgress.done();
                $("div.failure").text("Saveing Failure");
                $("div.failure").fadeIn(300).delay(1500).fadeOut(400);
            }
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            NProgress.done();
            $("div.failure").text("Saveing Failure");
            $("div.failure").fadeIn(300).delay(1500).fadeOut(400);
            console.log($scope.message);
        });

    };


})
    .config(function ($locationProvider, $sceProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
        $sceProvider.enabled(false);

    });
})(angular);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" ng-app="Sub_Ledger_Category_Create_app">
            <div class="box-body" ng-controller="Sub_Ledger_Category_Create_ctrl">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txt_Master_Subledger_Category_Name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sub Ledger Category</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input class="form-control" ng-model="SubLedgerCategoryModel.Sub_Ledger_Cat_Name" id="txt_Master_Subledger_Category_Name" name="txt_Master_Subledger_Category_Name" autofocus placeholder="Sub Ledger Category">
                        <input ng-model="SubLedgerCategoryModel.Sub_Ledger_Cat_ID" name="txt_Master_Subledger_Category_ID" id="txt_Master_Subledger_Category_ID" hidden />
                    </div>
                </div>



                <!-- /.box-body -->
                <div class="box-footer">
                    <button type="submit" value="Save" ng-click="InsertSubledgerCategory()" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Save</button>

                    <div class="text-red alert-box failure pull-right margin-r-5"></div>

                    <div class="text-green alert-box success pull-right margin-r-5"></div>


                </div>
                <!-- /.box-footer -->
            </div>

        </div>
```

Unfortunately I am unable to populate the view but in Console log I am able to view the data, helpful if anybody and help me.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct casing in ng-model ?

Comment: Dear Shyiu Yes its ok $scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel = {};

Comment: I have added the full JS I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only changed the following

scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel = data;

to

scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel = data[0]:

and its resolved my issue.

Comment: But, I would still support you to use ng-view(AngularJs routing to render the view)

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs prevents loading HTML in this way by default. You might be getting an error on browser console: **attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context**.

This is due to Angular's Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) mode (enabled by default). Have a look to [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/unsafe) for more information.

To resolve this issue you have 2 solutions:

1. $sce
   `$scope.thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(someHtmlVar);`
2. ngSanitize: include the angular-sanitize.min.js resource and add the dependency in module.

hope this will help.

Comment: First: I am not getting any error like attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context. in browser console. In browser console if it put console.log(data); it shows the data. As per your advice I have added angular-sanitize.min.js and .config(function $sceProvider) {        
 $sceProvider.enabled(false); }) but no result. However if I use  $.each(data, function (index, item) {              $("#txt_Master_Subledger_Category_Name").val(item.Sub_Ledger_Cat_Name);   $("#txt_Master_Subledger_Category_ID").val(item.Sub_Ledger_Cat_ID);
}); It shows the data. But I want angular shows it.

Comment: Why are you not using angular routing for rendering the view then? We can use ng-view (Angular's default) or ui-view(uiRoute, a third party routing module) for the same.

Comment: I just tried and got success using:

$scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel.Sub_Ledger_Cat_ID = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel.Sub_Ledger_Cat_ID); 

Try using this.

Comment: Also, I would suggest you to add the html content to a div and test if it is getting rendered or not.

Comment: Once I have done it the following is coming on Console Log [Object, Sub_Ledger_Cat_ID: undefined] But if I go through the details Its showing Array[1]0: ObjectSub_Ledger_Cat_ID: 3Sub_Ledger_Cat_Name: "Test" I Have used:  $scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel = data;
            $scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel.Sub_Ledger_Cat_ID = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel.Sub_Ledger_Cat_ID); Can you please help

Comment: Hello: I have used  $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                // alert(item.District)
                $scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel.Sub_Ledger_Cat_ID = item.Sub_Ledger_Cat_ID;
                $scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel.Sub_Ledger_Cat_Name = item.Sub_Ledger_Cat_Name;
               

            });

            $scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel.Sub_Ledger_Cat_ID = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel.Sub_Ledger_Cat_ID);
            $scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel.Sub_Ledger_Cat_Name = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel.Sub_Ledger_Cat_Name);

Comment: After doing the above the data is showing, can you please let me know can I omit  $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                // alert(item.District)
                $scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel.Sub_Ledger_Cat_ID = item.Sub_Ledger_Cat_ID;
                $scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel.Sub_Ledger_Cat_Name = item.Sub_Ledger_Cat_Name;
               

            }); Looking for your reply.

Comment: You can directly assign item variable to your $scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel and for making html trustful, still you need to add a loop. In Angular way, you can use angular.forEach() function to loop over the object. 

Your code should look somewhat like below:
$scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel = item;  angular.forEach($scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel,function(val,index){val.Sub_Ledger_Cat_Name  = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.SubLedgerCategoryModel.Sub_Ledger_Ca‌​t_Name)});

Please mark my answer as the solution if this helped.

Regards